# Delete using subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to delete via a subselect. The answers for this question do not solve my issue: [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause).

I found a hackish way to do this and wanted to get feedback on if this was the most optimal solution for doing a `DELETE with SUBSELECT` --

```
DELETE FROM main_history WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT * from (
     SELECT max(id) FROM main_history h GROUP BY instance_id, xpath
   ) x
)
```

Basically, I just add in a second (meaningless) subselect to get around the mysql error, which I receive if I just do a normal DELETE with the subselect:

```
DELETE FROM main_history WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT max(id) FROM main_history h GROUP BY instance_id, xpath
);
```

> You can't specify target table 'main_history' for update in FROM clause

Is this a good solution to the above issue?

**Update:** The subselect query performs much better than the join query. Here were my findings:

```
# 12m Subselect
DELETE FROM main_history WHERE id NOT IN (
 SELECT * from (
  SELECT max(id) FROM main_history h GROUP BY instance_id, xpath
 ) x
)
```

---

```
# 18m Join
Delete m1 from main_history m1 left join
(
  SELECT max(id) id FROM main_history h GROUP BY instance_id, xpath
) m2 on m1.id = m2.id
Where m2.id is null;
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: @Anand see updated question pls.

Comment: You can also add a new boolean field to the table: "newest_in_group" (with index). It would be true when you add a new entry, and also you set this value to false for all other entries where instance_id, xpath are the same (those could have a composite index). Then you can delete with a logarithmic query.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten yea I was previously storing a checksum to check for duplicate data, etc, but removed it was a bit tricky as we have both new inserts and updates, so it's a lot of overhead to keep track of it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right way is using delete join:

```
Delete m1 from main_history m1 left join
(
  SELECT max(id) id FROM main_history h GROUP BY instance_id, xpath
) m2 on m1.id = m2.id
Where m2.id is null;
```

Comment: want to benchmark the two different approaches using some fake data to see which performs better?

Comment: what would be the difference in the subselect approach vs. the join approach?

Comment: I would bet this is the most efficient method.

Comment: @Anand it's not -- see my updated question. But at least this answer offers a different approach, so it was nice to be able to test both out to see which one is faster (subselect) and cleaner (join).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table like this, then MySQL cant see the tablename from the SELECT:

```
DELETE FROM main_history WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT * from (SELECT max(id) FROM main_history h
      GROUP BY instance_id, xpath) AS x
   ) AS delrows
);
```

Comment: What would be the difference between deleting this way and then deleting via a join, as in the other answer?